# How to send messages from Windows Live Messenger to MS Lync users?

Tags: msn, lync-2010, lync

Is there a way to send message from Windows Live Messenger to MS Lync users?

Change some settings or something else?

Answer (score 4):

Yes - you can do this through configuration. Public IM Connectivity (PIC) needs to be enabled on the server.

[This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff945947.aspx) walks through how to enable PIC for IM and presence